# Get reference to current "style" object in QML?

Tags: qt, qml

Is there a way to get a reference to the current style object in QML?

Here's what I want to do:

```
Rectangle {
    border.color: style.accent
}
```

With the border color of the Rectangle being whatever is the accent color for the style being used.

I can think of a number of ways to do this by writing a bunch of code, but I was wondering if QML has a global style object I can just query instead.

Comment: If it's colors, how about `palette`? https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-palette.html

Comment: Each style has its own set of properties. Have a look at those two style definitions in your isntalled Qt `Qt/6.5.2/Src/qtdeclarative/src/quickcontrols/basic/qquickbasicstyle_p.h` and  `Qt/6.5.2/Src/qtdeclarative/src/quickcontrols/material/qquickmaterialstyle_p.h`. The Basic style doesn't have an `accentColor` property, so this will become an issue if you assume a certain property is available in a selected style. You can directly get the accent color by using `Material.accentColor`, but therfor you need the import and it might not be the current style.